# HTML Music app not supporting iPhone background play

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, xcode

I created a music app using html and js. It works in background when I run in safari (iOS)But it not supporting multitask and background when I run natively in iPhone.
Any suggestions.

Comment: please give details. i cannot parse this.

Comment: Basically when I run HTML music player in mobile safari it can contineo the pay even I got out of safari and open some other app. But when I run it as native app using mobile-web-app-capable it stop playing when I switch to some other apps. More over its not supporting multitask.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the difference between visiting the site in Safari vs standalone  (i.e. accessing it from the home screen, assuming the `mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag is present).

Currently, only iOS5 supports background audio playback for standalone web apps. Anything prior to that won't work.